# Web3 eth sendtransaction editable

Tags: web3js, ether

I want to make an eth payment on my website. Im unsing a simple sendtransaction. How can i hide the edit button? Or how can i make the transaction not editable?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The edit is not for the transaction to be edited but for the gas amount to be used, in case you want to change it.

Comment: On the top left corner there is an edit button. It stand for the eth amount. Isnt it?

Comment: The eth amount you are willing to spend on gas only, not the transaction amount